# Promise.all() throwing error while connecting to database Error: timeout exceeded when used with Node-Postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

I have Node.js express app with Postgres as a database. I'm using [pg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg) for database communication from the app.

This is how my `db.service` looks like

```
import { Pool } from 'pg';

const dbConfig = {/*my valid db configuration*/};

const pool = new Pool(dbConfig);

export const connectDB = async () => {
 let client;
 try {
  client = await pool.connect();
 } catch (error) {
  console.error('error while connecting to database', error);
  process.exit(1);
 }
 return client;
};
```

I have two queries as below

#1.

```
export const fetchUser = async (email) => {
const client = await connectDB();

  const query = `
    SELECT full_name FROM app.users
    WHERE  email = '${email}'
  `;

  let result;
  try {
    result = await client.query(query);
    if (result.rowCount) {
      return result.rows[0].full_name;
    }
  } catch (error) {
  } finally {
    await client.release();
  }
  return result;
};
```

#2

```
export const fetchWallet = async (email) => {
    const client = await connectDB();
    
      const query = `
        SELECT wallet_money FROM app.user_wallet
        WHERE  email = '${email}'
      `;
    
      let result;
      try {
        result = await client.query(query);
        if (result.rowCount) {
          return result.rows[0].wallet_money;
        }
      } catch (error) {
      } finally {
        await client.release();
      }
      return result;
    };
```

Now from one of my controller.js if I call these function separate await, no issues

ctrl.js

```
   const fullName = await fetchUser('some@gmail.com');
   const walletMoney = await fetchWallet('some@gmail.com');
```

No issues this way, however if I merge them into a single promise

```
   const $0= fetchUser('some@gmail.com');
   const $1= fetchWallet('some@gmail.com');
  
   const result = await Promise.all([$0, $1]);
```

this throws the below error

> **error while connecting to database Error: timeout exceeded when trying**
> **to connect at Error**

Please suggest why this error is popping up & how can I get rid of it?

Thanks!

Comment: This is related to your db connection file. Please add logs and check if the config is proper and also your db server is running correctly

Comment: @DeekshithHegde I don't think so because if that would have been the case in the approach #1 where I have separate `await` it executes with no issues

Answer (score 0):

That's happening because you are trying to connect to DB separately for every query.Try to create one connection and use it for all queries!